# dropna() not working for axis = 1 with the given threshold

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

For the given dataset

[image]

I performed a dropna on axis = 1 with threshold = 2

```
df.dropna(thresh=2,axis=1)
```

The output was

[image]

Which does not seem correct, what I expect is to drop column with index = 1 and 2 given that both columns have NaN occurences >= 2

The code works perfectly fine with axis=0

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df.dropna(thresh=6,axis=1)` for same dataframe.